# Event handling order in parent and child components Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, events, event-handling, angular2-components

I have a situation in which a parent and a child component have to listen to the same event, but the handling order is very important.

For example, in **parent.component.html**, I have

```
<child-component></child-component>
```

And I subscribe to the same event in both **parent.component.ts** and **child.component.ts**.

Can I know for sure which one will execute first, and if I can – which one is that?

Comment: Provide more html and code on how you handle events

Comment: @SurenSrapyan I would if I could, believe me.

Comment: Noone will answer this question if you dont provide a working demo or the actual code

Comment: @fromZerotoHero Is there something like fiddler for angular?

Comment: Yes, stackblitz.com . But i see you added that its about subscriptions. If you subscribe, you can console.log there and see. Also use Rxjs operators, like `do` (or `tap` if you use lettable operators) - `myObservable.do(() => console.log('i received value')).subscribe();`

Comment: @fromZerotoHero Yes, console.log() seems like a way to go, but can I guarantee the same behavior on any setup as it is on my computer and network speeds?

Comment: Well thats a theory. I dont like to talk about theory, as there might be many circumstances, but probably it will act the same on any environment